# Chrome not respecting media query specific width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, webstorm

So basically here is my problem, I designed a bootstrap webpage which changes and align content at different widths. Everything was working succesfully on Firefox, but when I tested it on Chrome media queries where applied at different widths.

For example if my media query is:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { //Bootstrap xs definition 
    .clickable{
        font-size: medium;
    }

    footer{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

That media query started acting after 767px in Firefox and 658px in Chrome. Also bootstrap definitions are not being applied at the correct width in Chrome browser´s.

Extra:

- I'm using Webstrom 2016.2 which mounts it on a local server (don´t know if that affects), since this only happens when I launch it using the icons on Webstorm
- My meta tags are:

```html
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {`? Never seen a media query without the prepended value.

Comment: Yes I also tried @media screen and... :(

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you loading your css files _after_ the bootstrap css?

Comment: just an idea: width might depend on current zoom. See http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/98448-font-size-difference-on-localhost-vs-actual-server/page__st__15 - it suggests that browsers may remember the zooming based on URL/protocol - can this be the issue? Chrome uses different zoom for page opened on built-in webserver, thus the result differs from the one you get when not using WebStorm/using different browser?

Comment: Yes I´m loading the files after bootstrap css, and if the zooming changed it would show on the Chrome toolbar (But it stays on 100% zoom) it dosen´t matter where the content is displayed (locally or on a built-in webserver)